# Android Call Intent Null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, call

Im at my wits end here. I have a Class which Implements the `OnClickListener` cous i need the same action on Buttons accros my Application. This used to work just fine. But since I added some functionality by getting some needed data from the app preferences. `startActivity` throws a null pointer exception.
Here is the class:

```
//Imports
public class CallClickListener extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    protected AppPreferences appPrefs;
    String contactPersonName;
    String contactPersonTelephone;
    String name;

    public CallClickListener(Context context){
        Log.d("TRACE", "init CallClick");
        appPrefs = new AppPreferences(context);

        try {

            JSONObject object = appPrefs.getConsultantObject();

            contactPersonName = object.getString("contactPersonName");
            contactPersonTelephone = object.getString("contactPersonTelephone");
            name = object.getString("name");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        final View v = view;

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
        alert.setTitle("Anrufen");
        alert.setMessage("Kontakt für " + name + ", " + contactPersonName + " anrufen");
        alert.setPositiveButton("Anrufen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+contactPersonTelephone));
                startActivity(callIntent);// this line throws the exception
            }
        });
        alert.setNegativeButton("Abbrechen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Abbruch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

The Strings are all there from appPrefs, i also tried with hardcoding a phonenumber just incase. the Alert works fine, but as soon as i hit the positive Button, the app crashes
I add the Listener like this:

```
bCall.setOnClickListener(new CallClickListener(getApplicationContext()));
```

I added the necessary Call permissions.

I'm fairly new to Android dev, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this.... make the context object that you passed in the constructor into a field variable. and change startActivity to `context.startActivity`. It will work then.

***EDIT:*** Highlighting the full solution.

`bCall.setOnClickListener(new CallClickListener(getApplicationContext()));`

**should be changed to** `YourActivityClass.this` instead of `getApplicationContext`.

Start Activity in the same task does not work with a context object that is not an `Activity`. So you need to either change the context to `Activity` or you start the activity in a new task. Also without calling startActivity on the context provided to your constructor you were getting the NPE because your `CallClickListerner` has no context.

Comment: That sounded promising, but has the same result :(

Comment: @M4tchB0X3r i just tried your code by harcoding the number. the alertdialog works. on clicking the button it does make a call. i am not sure why you are getting NPE

Comment: bCall.setOnClickListener(new CallClickListener(getApplicationContext())); should be YourActivityClass.this instead of getApplicationContext. Try that.

Comment: srym not quite the same, now i gget this error!
"Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?" not sure what that means

Comment: @SamarthJain i did suggest the same before but was not sure. so edited my answer again. coz he says alertdialog works

Comment: Yes ... that's what i was looking for... make the edit i told you in the previous comment and it'll work. Start Activity in the same task does not work with a context object that is not an Activity. So you need to either change the context to Activity or you start the activity in a new task. Also without calling startActivity on the context provided to your constructor you were getting the NPE because your CallClickListerner has no context.

Comment: @M4tchB0X3r i used a button with annonymous inner class and on button click used you alertdialog and the call works fine. i harcoded the number. You can check the edit. it works for me

Comment: got it working thx. the hint with YourActivityClass.this did it. CallClickListener.this as Raghunandan suggested obviously didnt work since thats the listener im adding.

Comment: Good to hear it works. But going forward you must understand why that error happened.

Comment: I do understand, thats why the answer sounded promising to start off with. I needed to pass the ativity context not application context, and start the intent over that

Comment: great... off to the next problem then :D

Comment: Lets hope not ;) *fingers crossed*

Answer (score 1):

Use activity context. Also check if you have initialized bCall. If you have not you will get NullPointerException.

```
     bCall.setOnClickListener(ActivityName.this);
```

Also check this link to know when to use activity context and when to use application context

[When to call activity context OR application context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context)

Edit:

Make sure you have added permission in manifest file

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

For reference use the below. My Class extends Activity

```
   Button b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 
   b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              final View v = v1;

                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                alert.setTitle("Anrufen");
                alert.setMessage("Kontakt für " );
                alert.setPositiveButton("Anrufen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:8095992052"));
                        startActivity(callIntent);// this line throws the exception
                    }
                });
                alert.setNegativeButton("Abbrechen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Abbruch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                alert.show();
        }

    });
```

Comment: Thnaks for the quick reply. I Obviously assign the button to a resource first. But when i try your code, i get the error 'CallClickListener' is not an enclosing class

Comment: I use the application context to get the application prefferences

Comment: @M4tchB0X3r i am checking again.

Comment: Yes i have. Like i said it used to work. but since implementing the dynamic strings it crashes

Comment: @M4tchB0X3r log this contactPersonTelephone and check whether this is null or not

Comment: that was the first thing i did, and its fine. i also tried with hardcoding the number like '(Uri.parse("tel:012345"));' same result

Comment: thx, but im adding the listener in another activity, like i said in the question. Jain got it right. thx for the effort tho

Comment: @M4tchB0X3r you had the button in another activity and you were trying do a on click on the same?

Comment: Like i said in OP, "i need the same action on Buttons accros my Application", so i add the CallClickListener where i need it. works like a charm now