# Android NullPointerException creating new Intent in Motorola device

Tags: android, image, nullpointerexception, picker, motorola

I have a button:

```
final Button dialogButtonFotoPerfil1 = (Button) dialogFotosPerfil
            .findViewById(R.id.botonFotoPerfil1);
    dialogButtonFotoPerfil1.setOnClickListener(new MediaGaleryActivity());
```

which I want to show an image picker.
MediaGaleryActivity.java is:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.gayworld.R;
import com.gayworld.utils.Utilidades;

public class MediaGaleryActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private static final int SELECT_IMAGE = 1;
    private static  String TAG; 

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TAG = "MediaGaleryActivity.onClick";
        Log.d(TAG, "Inicio.");
        Intent intent = null; 
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.botonFotoPerfil1: 

                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");    
                Log.d(TAG, "Error valor gallery "+intent.toString());
                  startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                            "Select Picture"),SELECT_IMAGE); 
            break; 
        default:
            break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      TAG = "MediaGaleryActivity.onActivityResult";
        Log.d(TAG, "Inicio.");

      if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==SELECT_IMAGE){
       Uri selectedImage=data.getData();
       String path=getPath(selectedImage);

       Bitmap bitmapImage=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
       ImageView image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
       image.setImageBitmap(bitmapImage);

      }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri){
         TAG = "MediaGaleryActivity.getPath";
            Log.d(TAG, "Inicio.");

      String[] filePathColumn={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

      Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
      cursor.moveToFirst();
      int columnIndex=cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);

      return cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    }

}
```

But I´m getting a NullPointerException.

Logcat:

```
05-25 13:52:15.287: D/MediaGaleryActivity.onClick(11620): Inicio.
05-25 13:52:15.295: D/MediaGaleryActivity.onClick(11620): Error valor gallery Intent { act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT typ=image/* }
05-25 13:52:15.295: D/AndroidRuntime(11620): Shutting down VM
05-25 13:52:15.295: W/dalvikvm(11620): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a2c1f8)
05-25 13:52:15.334: E/AndroidRuntime(11620): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 13:52:15.334: E/AndroidRuntime(11620): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-25 13:52:15.334: E/AndroidRuntime(11620):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
05-25 13:52:15.334: E/AndroidRuntime(11620):    at com.gayworld.screen.activity.MediaGaleryActivity.onClick(MediaGaleryActivity.java:34)
05-25 13:52:15.334: E/AndroidRuntime(11620):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
05-25 13:52:15.334: E/AndroidRuntime(11620):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
05-25 13:52:15.334: E/AndroidRuntime(11620):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-25 13:52:15.334: E/AndroidRuntime(11620):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-25 13:52:15.334: E/AndroidRuntime(11620):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-25 13:52:15.334: E/AndroidRuntime(11620):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
05-25 13:52:15.334: E/AndroidRuntime(11620):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 13:52:15.334: E/AndroidRuntime(11620):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-25 13:52:15.334: E/AndroidRuntime(11620):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
05-25 13:52:15.334: E/AndroidRuntime(11620):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
05-25 13:52:15.334: E/AndroidRuntime(11620):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I get this error and I don´t know what I can do more.
I have been reading a lot of blogs, answers,.. I also ask for google help... but nothing.
I always get the same error.
Any idea??
Because I´m really stuck with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in your `Logcat`, few lines more below there should be something like `Caused by`. Which line is it indicating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your MediaGalleryActivity has context?

Check this out, the user was doing something similar and getting a NPE on startActivity -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/16748203/2114852

Other than that, you'd have to provide the full logcat as the comment suggests.